# Excute a script in php and pass variable to remaining script

Tags: php, exec

I hope someone can help with this one.

I would like to replace the sever login code with a file that I can call.  The idea is that I have several servers I need to log into and I don't want to keep replacing this code with new.  Instead I will use an If Else routine to call the right login details.

So what I have so far is a **robconfig.php** file with the server login details and error code

```
<?php

$serverName = "//serverName\instanceName";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"xx", "PWD"=>"password");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Could not connect.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

And I've tried placing it into my existing php file using **exec() system() and passthru()** but have not been able to get the variables e.g. "$conn" passed through to the rest of the script

```
<?php

// CONNECT TO SERVER
system('php -q robfig.php');

// DATA for BOX TABLE 1
$tsqBl = "SELECT * FROM FactBox";
$stmtB1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsqBl);

$dataB1 = "";
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtB1, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){

$dataB1 .= "$row[2]";
}


// ECHO STATEMENTS TO CHECK DATA IF WORKING PROPERLY

echo "$dataB1";

// CLOSE THE CONNECTION TO THE SERVER
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmtB1);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

I get this error message.

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpConfigTest.php on line 8

Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: have you tried use require_once 'robfig.php'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `require_once('robconfig.php');`